# How to show the other products of the product categories the product is included (woocommerce)?

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce, sidebar, product

The need is to show on the single product page sidebar the other products in the categories the product is included.

For example:
A bike is included in product categories (x,y,z)
When clicked at Bike, I am @ [the product single page](http://kayabike.hulq.nl/product/cortina-u4-transport-dames/).
In the sidebar right, i want to show all the products of X + Y + Z - Bike.

How can I reach this?

[Current & desired situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8jni.png)

- using Wordpress, WooCommerce, WidgetLogic and Divi template

Comment: default sidebars cant do that. You could buy this one: http://codecanyon.net/item/wc-products-by-category-widget/5889616

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to achieve the results:
in the sidebar.php

```
if(is_product()) {
// if you are on single product page
$productObj =get_queried_object();
$categories = get_the_terms($productObj->id,'product_cat');
$cat_list = array();
foreach($categories as $category)
{$cat_list[] = $category->term_id;};

$posts = get_posts(
  array(
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'fields'        => 'ids',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'exclude' => array($productObj->id),
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
        'terms'     => $cat_list,
        'field'     => 'term_id'
      )
    )
  )
);

 // now you can iterate through the $posts and show the appropriate list.
}
```